# Create script from console input in R

Tags: r, statistics

Instead of first creating a script in R and then executing it afterwards, is it possible to do it the other way around?

I.e. I would type some user input in the console, and afterwards have R compile all the user inputs from the console (without the resulting outputs), to a script for later user.

Comment: The Emacs ESS mode has been supporting this for maybe a decade -- just save your session as a file with extension ".Rt" and transcript mode makes it a breeze to re-execute statement by statement (as ESS what were statements and what not).

Answer (score 4):

Commands that you type into the console are stored in the history file  (see `?savehistory`).  You can edit that to get your script.

Comment: A vist to ?savehstory was productive in that I learned about `timestamp()`: I will add this to my .Rprofile : `timestamp(stamp = Sys.Date() )`

Comment: Actually needs to be `utils:::timestamp(stamp = Sys.Date() )` since .Rprofile is executed before utils gets loaded.